# Get the names of XML nodes using XPATH on Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

I have an xml document as follows:

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

On hive, I am able to use `xpath` to retrieve the text of each node in the XML document using the following command:

`select xpath(xml_text,'//*[name()='note']//text()') from table_test;`

However, I cannot figure out which XPATH command to use on Hive to retrieve the XML node names of the text
For the example above, I want to be able to return 
`["to","from","heading","body"]`, which represent the XML nodes for the tokens in the XML files. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can only use `xpath` to get either text or element attributes - not names of nodes.

So, there are two options: You could write(or find online) a custom UDF that returns the name of a node for a given xpath.

Or, you could use this hack:

```
select xpath(regexp_replace(xml_text,'<([\\w]+),'<$1 nodename=\'$1\' '),note/*/@nodename)
```

Explanation: it adds the nodename attribute to any xml element. (`<to> -> <to nodename='to'>`) It may also add it in some text, but since you only extract the `nodename` attribute - it shouldn't matter.

By the way, you could rewrite your text query to:

`select xpath(xml_text,'note/*/text()') from table_test;`

Comment: Thanks Alex, Any recommendation for a custom UDF?

Comment: @DonGorgon You could take the [original hive xpath UDF](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/xml/GenericUDFXPath.java) and change line 83 from `getNodeValue()` to `getNodeName()`. Maybe add some test to make sure the node is an element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That will definitely work.